# Question with articles and proper nouns on techinal terms

Tags: grammar, articles, proper-nouns

This one is the hardest for me to learn/grasp. From what I read, some proper nouns are allowed to have the word "The", while some are not. Which one is correct/incorrect:

> - Upload it to the Windows Store.
> - Upload it to Windows Store.
> - Upload it to the Windows store.

Do you usually add "The" for technical proper nouns? The Internet, The Windows Operating system, etc?

Answer (score 0):

We use the definite article before names of unique things which are known both to the speaker and the listener. In this sense, the Windows Store is unique and known to all.

*"Upload it to **the** Windows Store" is correct usage.*

[Here](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/) is a detailed list of occasions when to use and not to use '**the**'